# attend to an event with facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

i get all attending user from an event with the sdk with this code:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/'.$facebook_event_id.'/attending');
```

but i want to try attend with my user to the event with this code (like in this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios#eventrsvp):

```
$attend = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/'.$facebook_event_id.'/attending');
```

why didn't work the post?

Comment: What do you mean by the "post didn't work"? Are you receiving an error response? Without sharing your access token, does it have the 'rsvp_event' permission (required for your use case)?

Comment: thanks for your answer. i used the wrong permission.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, and confirmed by the developer asking the question, in order to RSVP to an event, you need to POST to the '[EVENT_ID]/attending' edge with an access token with the 'rsvp_event' permission.